# class template in c++ with functions

Tags: c++

```
#AL.hpp
template <typename A>
class AL
{
    public:
        void print(A *source, A *dest, unsigned int size);
    private:
        A *data;
        unsigned int size;
        unsigned int capacity;
 }

namespace {
    template <typename A>
    unsigned int size s_size = 20;
    void print(A *source, A *dest, unsigned int size)
    {
      ....
    }
 }

template <typename A>
AL<X>& AL<X>::push(A input)
{
    capacity *= 2;
    A *new_data = new A[capacity];
    print(data, new_data, size);
 }
```

I am just wondering how to format this (please don't mind the code). When I run my full code, it says that A is not defined in the namespace. I'm not sure how to pass in the class template to my namespace.

Comment: Can you post code that is at least close to being valid?

Comment: Are you trying to provide the definition for the member function in a different namespace?

Comment: Are you trying to make the whole `namespace` templated? Or the function `print`? Because you *can't* make templated namespaces. If you want a templated "namespace" you have to make a `struct` with only static members.

Comment: i want to use the print function in another function that has template, but i get an error message saying that A is undefined in the namespace. i'm not sure how to get the values to pass through one another.

Comment: So you want the *function* to be templated? Then look again at the source, especially where you placed the `template` declaration for the function (or rather, it's not a `template` declaration for the function, but for the variable declaration, which itself is not valid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#AL.hpp
template <typename A>
class AL
{
    public:
        AL(A array_list);
        AL(const AL& other);
        AL& operator=(const AL& other);
        ~AL;
        void print(A *source, A *dest, unsigned int size);
}

namespace {
    unsigned int size s_size = 20;
    template <typename A>
    void print(A *source, A *dest, unsigned int size)
    {
       ....
    }
 }
```

If the problem or error is your 'print' function is seemed unnamed then this is the solution.I hope this will help.